# Missing Host File - Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, restore, hosts

I've looked through the internet and even saw a similair posted question, but didn't really give the answer I was looking for, so I'll see if I can get any better luck.

I recently had to modify my host file and add an IP and urls to it for some hosting migration I was performing.  Well the migration has completed and I went back to change my host file back, I simply highlighted the text I entered earlier, hit delete, then Control-O then Control-X.

I soon saw that I was having errors when browsing on the internet and through it may have to do with my host file.  I went back to find the complete file empty.  I entered in the basic:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

And attempted to save it and got this error:

```
[ERROR WRITING private/etc/hosts: NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY]
```

Everytime I try to save a new version, it simply says that I cannot since the file cannot be found.  Can anyone advise me on what I should do to restore my host file to the way it was.  I swear I'll never tinker around in here ever again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `/private/etc/hosts`. You're missing the `/` at the beginning.

Comment: WOW... that was actually it.  Thank you. that was easy.